# jquery tabs, slider and read more link -- read more only working on the first article

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, pagination, slideshow

@roXon solved this. See his response below should you be interested in using this.

I'm using the jquery's 'tabs' plus a 'read more' functionality for each of my articles, but the read more is not functioning as it should. The 'read more' is not extending to each of my articles, it's only working on the first (top) article.

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/evanmoore/yNC9G/1/show/

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/yNC9G/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/AzTPR/2/)

used:

`$(this).parent().prev('.wrap').animate({`

You had an extra comma and some little errors.

What have I done to make it work:
on top I created an `each` method for your .wrap - to store into `.data()` each .wrap height.

```
$(function(){
    $('#postsBig .wrap').each(function(){
        var wraph = $(this).height();
        $(this).data('h',wraph);
    });
});
```

Than I isolated the script `if` that checks if the .wrap need to have the 'footer' read more.

```
$('.wrap').each(function(){
    var wrap = $(this);
    var wraph = wrap.data('h');
    if(wraph >= slideHeight){
        wrap.height(slideHeight);
        wrap.next('.read-more').append('<a href="#">Click to Read More</a>');
    }
});
```

Than I just edited a bit your codes to get the good element to trigger and the search for the proper .data height for the right .wrap element:

```
$('.read-more a').click(function(){
    var defHeight = $(this).parent().prev('.wrap').data('h');
    var curHeight = $(this).parent().prev('.wrap').height();
    if(curHeight <= slideHeight){
        $(this).parent().prev('.wrap').animate({
          height: defHeight
        }, 500);
        $(this).html('Close');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().prev('.wrap').animate({
          height: slideHeight
        }, 500);
        $(this).html('Click to Read More');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: There's still one issue with heights that I'm resolving right now! I'll post a fiddle soon. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that. wow! thank you. I noticed the height is only adapting to the first article's height. again, thank you.

Comment: that's awesome. it's perfect. you got it man! :) thanks so much. now, that did the trick! can't thank you enough!:)

Comment: Oh... ok! glad it helped! Cheers! happy coding! see ya

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$('.read-more a').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('.read-more a').live("click", function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling .height() on a class of elements, so it will return the height of the first match.  This isn't what you want.  You're also calling animate on the class selector not on the element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when the tab is not active then the height of the `.wrap` inside is 0.

Of course, roXon posted a great solution that stores the height on load and will make the read-more link change for all slides. And this may be the intended effect. I'd like to point out that it may be better to put the read-more div outside the slides because you are effecting them all and they will all be the same value everytime.

I wanted to see what it would be like to expand only the slide that the read-more was clicked on without storing the original height in the data object. Here's what I came up with:

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natedavisolds/yNC9G/4/)

First, the css:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 120px;
}
```

then, the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".pagination").tabs(".slides li", {
    event: 'mouseover',
     rotate: true,
        }).slideshow({
            clickable: false,
            autoplay: false,
            interval: 4000 // in milliseconds 4000 = 4 seconds
        });

    var closedSlideHeight = 120; // px

    $('.slides .read-more').click(function() {
        var $readMore = $(this),
            $wrap = $readMore.siblings('.wrap');

        var fullHeight = function() {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            $wrap.children().each(function() {
                totalHeight += parseInt($(this).outerHeight(true));
            }); 

            return totalHeight.toString() + "px";
        };

        var isClosed = function() {
            return (closedSlideHeight >= parseInt($wrap.height()) && !($wrap.height() == 0));
        };

        var closeWrap = function() {
            $wrap.animate({'height': (closedSlideHeight.toString() + "px")});
            $readMore.html('<a href="#">Click to Read More</a>');
        };

        var openWrap = function() {
            $wrap.animate({'height': fullHeight() });  
            $readMore.html('<a href="#">Close</a>');
        };

        if (isClosed()) {
            openWrap();
        } else {
            closeWrap();
        }
    }).click();
})
```